# Jekyll case-insensitive sorting

Tags: tags, jekyll, liquid, case-insensitive

I'm trying to create a tags list in Jekyll. Some of the tags are "accessibility", "CSS", and "JavaScript". So my Jekyll code to create the list looks like this:

```
<ul>
  {% for item in (0..site.tags.size) %}{% unless forloop.last %}
    {% capture this_word %}{{ tag_words[item] }}{% endcapture %}
    <li>
      <a href="#{{ this_word | cgi_escape }}" class="tag">{{ this_word }}
        <span>({{ site.tags[this_word].size }})</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  {% endunless %}{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

However, the rending of the list isn't alphabetical. It's first case-sensitive, capital words first; so my example tags above are rendered in this order:

- CSS
- JavaScript
- accessibility

Is there a way to make the sorted list case-insensitive?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a `sort_natural` filter in liquid, but it [doesn't work with `site.tags`](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/6290).

The trick is to generate an array with all tags names

```
{% comment %} Creates an empty array {% endcomment %}
{% assign tags = "" | split:"" %}

{% comment %}Creates an array of tags names{% endcomment %}
{% for t in site.tags %}
  {% assign tags = tags | push: t[0] %}
{% endfor %}
```

Sort them naturally (case insensitive)

```
{% assign sorted_tags = tags | sort_natural %}
```

Based on this sort, print tags counts

```
<ul>
{% for t in sorted_tags %}
  <li>{{ t }} : {{ site.tags[t].size }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Why not just create an empty array with a more intuitive `{% assign tags = "" | split: "" %}`?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the mentioned [issue of sort_natural filter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49549166/4058484) has been fixed. You may try to use it directly:

```
<ul>
{% for t in site.tags sort_natural %}
  <li>{{ t }} : {{ site.tags[t].size }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

This becomes more complex once you have to find a post by its name. Here's a solution to sort posts in an archive list alphabetically:

```
  {% assign post_names = "" | split:"" %}
  {% for post in tag.last %}
    {% assign post_names = post_names | push: post.title %}
  {% endfor %}

  {% assign sorted_post_names = post_names | sort_natural %}

  {% for post_name in sorted_post_names %}
    {% assign matched_post = site.posts | where:"title",post_name %}
    {% assign post = matched_post[0] %}
    …
  {% endfor %}
```

The trick is to find the post with `where` from the overall list of posts.